# Ошибка многопоточной сборки в Makefile

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, g++, makefile

---

#### Окружение:

- Виртуализация: VirtualBox 6.1
- Host OS: Windows Server 2016 Datacentr
- Guest OS: UbuntuServer 18.04
- Директория с исходниками находится на диске windows
- В guestos доступ к ней прокинут через VB shared folder
- Диск обычный SATA6

Сборка происходит под десяток различных тулчейнов в основном всё gcc.
В Makefile ни чего необычного, около 20 либ собирающиеся g++ и gcc.

---

#### Проблема

При многопоточной сборке с различной переодичностью возникает ошибка, в независимости от таргета или тулчейна:

```
In file included from ../../lib/boost/predef/os.h:18:0,
                 from ../../lib/boost/predef.h:17,
                 from ../../include/share/cpp11check.h:2,
                 from ../../include/share/mplcshare.h:44,
                 from ./mplc_opcua.h:17,
                 from ./stdafx.h:58,
                 from core_opcua_server/source/SubscriptionServer.cpp:39:
../../lib/boost/predef/os/linux.h:12:31: error: ../../lib/boost/predef/make.h: Invalid argument
 #include <boost/predef/make.h>
                               ^
```

В место **boost/predef/make.h** может быть любой **header**

Изначально из-за проблем с зависимостями сборка паралелилась на уровне тулчейна, т.е запускалось 4 make для разных платформ и там эта проблема возникала чаще.

Сейчас запускается один make c **-j4**, ошибка появляется реже но не пропала полностью.

---

#### Вопросы:

- В чём может быть проблема подобного поведения?
- Есть ли какие то ограничения на количество открываемых файлов с gusetos?
- Есть ли способ диагностировать в чём заключается реальная ошибка?

---

<sup>**PS**:</sup>

<sup>Перенести srcdir на guestos на текущий момент не представляется возможным, как и собирать на отдельной машине с linux.</sup>

<sup>на локальной машине пока не воспроизводилось, возможно из-за малого количества попыток(нет возможности ждать 3-4 часовые билды), а возможно из-за nvme ssd.</sup>

---

### Ещё раз хочу отдельно подчеркнуть:

- проблема не в **отсутствии файлов или их путях и не в флагах gcc**
- **нет ни каких "гонок"** все исходники гарантировано лежат в нужной директории до начала сборки.
- Эта ошибка решается тупо изменением опции make c -j4 на -j1, что замедляет полную сборку в 3-4 раза и длится вместо 2-3 часов все 8-10, из-за чего и возникла проблема

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105493/discussion-on-question-by-arenoros-----makefile).